# WiX: Install Shortcut as Feature

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am attempting to build an installer which installs shortcuts when a certain feature is selected.

The following is what I have so far, and it's not doing the trick.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="GUID-1785-41F7-B845-08812B091FA2" Name="Auction OS" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Company" UpgradeCode="GUID-3626-482F-ACFC-721551EBA9F8">
        <Package Id="*" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Description="The Installation Package" Comments="Copyright Company" />
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <Media Id="1" EmbedCab="yes" Cabinet="n.cab" />
        <Feature Id="FullProduct" Title="Full Setup" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="AOSComponents" />
            <Feature Id="accounting_feat" Title="Accounting Type" Description="Accounting SQL queries." Display="expand" Level="1">
            </Feature>
            <Feature Id="email_bos_sc_feat" Title="Email BOS Shortcut" Description="A RunJob application service which automatically e-mails bills of sale to buyers." Display="expand" Level="1">
                <ComponentRef Id="email_bos_sc_comp"/>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Id="block_print_sc_feat" Title="Block Print Shortcut" Description="A RunJob application service which prints bills of sale on the block." Display="expand" Level="1">
                <ComponentRef Id="block_print_sc_comp"/>
            </Feature>
            <Feature Id="dealer_kiosk_sc_feat" Title="Dealer Kiosk Shortcut" Description="A kiosk application which allows dealers to print their own bidder badges and gate passes." Display="expand" Level="1">
                <ComponentRef Id="dealer_kiosk_sc_comp"/>
            </Feature>
        </Feature>
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
    </Product>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
            <Component Id="email_bos_sc_comp" Guid="GUID-DE67-40FF-81BE-80310D3B9CC8">
                <Shortcut Id="emailbosLNKdesktop" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="AOS Email BOS" Target="emailbosBAT" Icon="auctionedge_icon" IconIndex="0" Directory="DesktopFolder" Description="A RunJob application service which automatically e-mails bills of sale to buyers."/>
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\AOS\email_bos_sc" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="block_print_sc_comp" Guid="GUID-AD89-4D19-B186-7674F1DD6F99">
                <Shortcut Id="blockprintLNKdesktop" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="AOS Block Print" Target="blockprintBAT" Icon="auctionedge_icon" IconIndex="0" Directory="DesktopFolder" Description="A RunJob application service which prints bills of sale on the block." />
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\AOS\block_print_sc" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="dealer_kiosk_sc_comp" Guid="GUID-AD03-44E5-BB86-6C0BF2A1FE7A">
                <Shortcut Id="dealerkioskLNKdesktop" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="AOS Dealer Kiosk" Target="dealerkioskBAT" Icon="auctionedge_icon" IconIndex="0" Directory="DesktopFolder" Description="A kiosk application which allows dealers to print their own bidder badges and gate passes." />
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\AOS\dealer_kiosk_sc" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

How can I achieve "if this feature is selected, create a shortcut to a file which was installed by this installer on the desktop"?

Additionally, I'd like to not have to install registry keys if I can avoid it. I just want a shortcut based on a condition... Seems a lot more difficult than it should be.

Comment: What exactly is happening? Your code should basically work. Unfortunately there is no way to avoid the registry values (unless you use files as the keypaths, which isn't practical in this case).

Comment: @zett42 thanks.  i was able to make progress on this.  after removing the PathEdit Control from the PathPromptDlg, i was able to display that dialog in the UI sequence and exit the installation normally.  will have to do some more digging to determine what exactly the problem with this Control is.